# React Native Fetch Authorization Header not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, api

I recently setup a REST API to authentify my users using their license key, tested in Node.js using axios and it worked just fine. This is how it looked :

```
var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://myapi?key=mykey',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'myauthorization',
  }
};
axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Returned, as expected `{success: true}`

However, when I tried doing the same exact thing in React Native using fetch it didn't work at all and I got `{success: false}` everytime.

```
let auth = await fetch("https://myapi?key=mykey", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'myauthorization'
        }
      });
      auth = await auth.json();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(auth))
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Could you share what you put in `myauthorization`? Are you using the keyword `Bearer`?

Comment: use headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer myauthorization'
        }

Comment: Added  `{ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'0}` @polcats, didn't work, I am not using the type Bearer @Birender Pathania so it didn't work neither.

Comment: Just curious, since you're already using axios, why did you not use axios in React Native as well? I have implemented codes that fetched data from an API before, but the framework I used was `ky` https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky

Comment: I'll try KY, also tried axios in react native but didn't work neither.